# Steps to restore one table from impdp in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I need to import only one table from a full backup (expdp) to a newly create table on the same database.

So can i import the table directly with a new name? or i have to create a new table first with the same parameters then import?

```
impdp hr DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=expschema.dmp TABLES=hr.employees REMAP_TABLE=hr.employees:emps
```

Another question will remap_table effect my already exist employees table? or it will only create a new table called emps and import the data of employees from the dump to it?

...................... Update ......................

I found that there is no remap_table in oracle 10g so can i use this method:

```
create user johny identified by 1234;
grant create session to johny;
impdp  system/****** DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1   DUMPFILE=expschema.dmp  LOGFILE= tb_imp.log  TABLES='HR.employees'  REMAP_SCHEMA=HR: johny;
```

We need the table temporarily only so i can drop johny later. also the above method will not effect the original employees table in the hr schema , right?

Comment: That's correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will import the table employees from your dump file and remame it to emps, if an employees table exists it will not be affeted, if the emps table already exists it will not do anything.
You can change the behavior when a table exists by using the table_exists_action parameter either specifiying:

- TRUNCATE => truncate the table if exists and import data from the
  dump
- REPLACE => will first replace the table with the definition
     from the dump and then import the data
- APPEND => will append the
     data to the table leaving the existing data in.